# relevant to+dependent on a specific place, situation or condition

Tags: single-word-requests

context sensitive?

i.e.

'provide a set of solutions through _ mediums'

Comment: Relevant, hah? Or *corresponding* might work?

Comment: May you write the question? As it is, it's not clear enough to get the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I understand the question, I would go with [*appropriate*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/appropriate), [*suitable*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/suitable) or [*adequate*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/adequate).

**Update:** we have settled on [*apropos*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apropos). Other words we have discussed include [*relevant*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/relevant) and [*opportune*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/opportune). See the comments.

Comment: Those 3 options would still require a qualifier. Here is another example: 'the information provided by the spy was _' thanks

Comment: *Relevant, pertinent, specific, to the point, exact, spot on*? These wouldn't work in your first example, but *context sensitive* wouldn't work in either. *Adequate* would, and I'm not sure what qualifier you think it would require.

Comment: my thinking is that 'relevant' can be used. But relevant is qualified through the context of the conversation in which it is used or is taking place at the time. What if i am trying to say that the information was relevant AND timely.

Comment: Umm, how about *opportune*?

Comment: it could be i am misunderstanding the word relevant but if I make a sentence like: 'we aim to help you by providing solutions through relevant? context sensitive? mediums'. It seems not right. Maybe appropriate is correct in this application but it also seems to say there is a right (appropriate) and wrong (inappropriate) way of doing it.

Comment: Well, yeah, words have connotations that you can't get rid of, but in this case I would say that the connotation is actually a good thing, isn't it? I mean, if you don't provide inappropriate/inadequate solutions, that's surely a good thing for *all* connotations of "inappropriate"/"inadequate".

Comment: 'connotation' that's a good word. and yes it is a good thing, just not the thing. Same reason I felt oppurtune, which was close, did not quite hit the mark.

Comment: Okay. I'll leave this up until I have a flash of genius or someone else chimes in with something better.

Comment: thanks, it is much appreciated. I have a feeling I have come across this word before

Comment: I just hope it wasn't something as obscure as [*apropos*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apropos?show=1&t=1295984647).

Comment: haha, could it be more apropos. just never imagined it would be so ugly and obscure. Thank you and how do you get the credit for this (though it does not seem like you need it)

Comment: I have updated the answer, and if you feel that it answers your question now, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark to the left of it. I'm not in dire need of the points, but one of our goals as a site is to have a high ratio of accepted answers.